# modulus of negative numbers in Python

Tags: python, modulus

```
23 % -5 = -2
23 % 5 = 3
```

Can someone explain to me how I can understand this because I have an exam tomorrow. I want to say its because `-5 * -5 =25` then `25 -2 = 23` which is how they get the `23`. Is this correct?

Comment: This isn't relate to Python so much as it is to mathematics in general. http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52343.html

Comment: @WaleedKhan, the answer will be different for different languages so it very much *is* a Python question.

Comment: You can use `math.fmod` to get the same behavior as in C or Java.

Answer (score 8):

In Python, the sign of the remainder is the same as the sign of the *denominator* (which differs from languages like C, where it is the same as the sign of the *numerator*).

Mathematically, you are always guaranteed that if `a, b = divmod(n, d)`, then `a*d + b == n`.

Note that `23//5 == 4` and `23//-5 == -5` (Python always does floor division). Thus, we have `4*5 + 3 == 23` and `-5*-5 - 2 == 23`, as you have said.

Comment: Guido explains this in some more detail in this blog post: [Why Python's Integer Division Floors](http://python-history.blogspot.ch/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Lets write it out as N=kM+R.

We have 23 = -5*(-5) - 2, and 23 = 4*5 + 3.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of looking at problem for your purposes is to consider the definition that:

a mod n = R where the remainder R must satisfy 0<= R

So for mod -5 arithmetic, 0<= R < -4 i.e. R can be one of 0, -1, -2, -3, -4

that is you effectively subtract (or add) n from a until you bring R into the range above:

So

23 % 5 is (23-4*5) = 23-20 = 3

but

23 % -5 is (23+5*(-5)) = 23-25 = -2

Answer (score 0):

Well, 23 % 5  = 3 since 4*5 = 20 and when you divide 23 by 20 you obtain a remainder of 3. You can think of it as the closet you can go without going over.

As for 23 % -5, well that answer differs from one programming language to another.

For Python it's -2 because it will always return the value of the divisor and it's because 5*5 = 25 and when you divide 23 by 25 in Python you obtain a remainder of -2 (since it must be negative because the divisor was negative) so we have 25 - 2 = 23.

It's worth noting that the formal mathematical definition states that b is a positive integer.

Comment: Actually, no. The formal mathematical definition says that certain numbers are equivalent modulo the modulus. The equivalence classes are *commonly* taken to be `[0], ... [n-1]`, but they don't have to be. `[42]` and `[-99]` are perfectly good equivalence classes mod 2.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I was saying. In the form a(mod b), **a** can be any integer value. Hence, [2] is congruent to [-3] modulo 5. It's the **b** that must be a positive integer in the formal mathematical definition. [Article on Modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic)

Comment: Ah. You never did define `b`, so I made an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

% in Python uses "Modulo operation" ; **it's different from taking the reminder of a division operation such that.**

```
a - int(a/n) * n
```

although it is sometimes equivalent in some computer languages.

The math expression can be found explict here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

So obviously, in Python "%" operation uses the following expression:

```
mod(a, n) = a - n * floor(a / n)
```

Therefore,

23%-5 = mod(23,-5) = 23 - (-5) * floor(23/-5) = 23 - (-5) * -5 = -2

and

23%5 =  mod(23, 5) = 23 - 5 * floor(23/5) = 23 - 5 * 4 = 3

In addition, you my find it's interesting that

-23%5 = mod(-23,5) = (-23) - 5 * floor(-23/5) = -23 - 5 * (-5) = 2

since floor() action will take the integer value toward negative infinity.